# Angular2 split string (pipe?)

Tags: split, angular

Is it possible to use something similar to `{{mystr | split(last) }}` somehow?

I'm hoping there is a pipe included already.

Comment: could you provide more details

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a custom pipe for this. You could implement this this way:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val:string, params:string[]):string[] {
    return val.split(params[0]);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
{{mystr | split:last }}
```

where `last` is a property of your component that corresponds to the separator.

Comment: How to use pipe that return an array?

Comment: Note -  say you wanted to get a specific element of the array (e.g. the second element), you would do:  `{{(mystr | split:"\n")[1] }}`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what `last` is.  I'll guess that you mean you want the last set of characters from the string, if you split the string up by some separator.  E.g., if the string is `abc,def,ghi` and the separator is `,` then you want `ghi`.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'splitLast' })
export class SplitLastPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value:string, [separator]):string {
    let splits = value.split(separator);
    if(splits.length > 1) {
      return splits.pop();
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

```
{{mystr | splitLast:','}}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Em76okrshLoke6KDr1Am?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: How do I reverse this to get first characters?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj, use shift() instead of pop().

Comment: How can i pass "Regex"? Ex : {{mystr | splitLast:'"(?:^|\\s)\\#(\\w+)"'}}

Comment: getting error: Binding element 'separator' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts