# Splitting string in p-datatable PrimeNG Angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a string with multiple environment names splitted with a semicolumn like this "C#;PHP;Java".

Now I'm using the p-datatable from PrimeNG for Angular, I'm running the newest Angular 4.

I'm having some difficulties with splitting this string to an unordered list in 1 cell. I thought that I had to build a pipe to split this, so my pipe code is

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'splitStringInListItems'
})
export class SplitStringInListItems implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value: string): string[] {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return value.split(";");
  }
}
```

This is the p-column I came up with:

```
<p-column header="Omgeving" field="Environment">
      <ng-template let-internship="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="envir in internship.Environment | splitStringInListItems">{{envir}}</li>
        </ul>
        <!--<span [style.color]='blue'>{{internship.Environment}}</span>-->
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Can someone help me out a bit :) Help is much appreciated.

### UPDATE

I've fixed it myself! :)

```
<p-column header="Omgeving" field="Environment">
      <ng-template let-internship="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let env of internship.Environment | splitStringInListItems">{{env}}</li>
        </ul>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793717/angular2-split-string-pipe

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, but that isn't problem. I do have the same pipe and I know how to use it, but I don't how to make a custom field in a PrimeNG datatable which implements the pipe and allows me to create a repeat of list items.

Comment: update the post with some json data and expected output !