# Angular Understanding Property Binding

Tags: angular, typescript

Say I have this in the ts file:

```
  arrImages = ['Front', 'Back', 'Left', 'Right'];
  Front = "...";
  Back = "...";
  Left = "...";
  Right = "...";
  ChangeImage(pImageView) {
      console.log(pImageView)
  }
```

And this in the html file:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let Item of arrImages">
    <label>{{Item}}</label>
    <img src="{{Item}}">
    <button (click)="ChangeImage(Item)">Change</button>
</ng-container>
```

The **label** comes out as `<label>Front</label>` or `<label>Back</label>` etc. Which is correct.

The **button** comes out as `<button (click)="ChangeImage('Front')">Change</button>` or `<button (click)="ChangeImage('Back')">Change</button>` etc. Which is correct.

But how do I get the **img** to come out as `<img [src]="Front">` or `<img [src]="Back">`?? Because I can't get the image src to link with the ts variables. I tried all of these:

```
<img src="Item">
<img src="{{Item}}">
<img [src]="Item">
<img [src]="'Item'">
<img [src]="{{Item}}">
<img [src]="'{{Item}}'">
```

Comment: the problem is that if you have <img src="Front"> or <img src]"Back">, both are not valid values for src property, they do not link to an img.

Comment: `<img src="{{ imgPath }}">` works perfectly fine for me. But Item in your case does not refer to your image path. It refers to the strings in your arrImages array. You should put imgs path in your array. Then you should make a custom pipe that allow you to extract only img name from image path and use `<label>{{Item | split:last}}`here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793717/angular2-split-string-pipe. Another solution is to make a class with two attributes imgPath and imgName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets notation to pass correct binding:

```
<img [src]="this[Item]">
```

Comment: Super perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `arrImages` contains only strings that are not correct images path.

Two ways for dealing with this:

---

**First way - Custom pipe**

Change `arrImages` items to valid images path like:

`arrImages = ['Front.png', 'Back.png', etc...]`
(you can remove your other variables)

Then, make a custom pipe to extract image name from image path

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'extractednamefromfilepath'
})

export class ExtractNameFromFilePathPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
  transform(val:string) : string 
  {
    // Split full path into small chunks of path (img/image.png => ['img', 'image.png']
    var splittedPath = value.split('/');

    // Sub the 4 last char of the last splittedPath chunk ('image.png' => 'image')
    return splittedPath[splittedPath.length - 1]
          .substring(splittedPath[splittedPath.length - 1].length - 4);
  }
}
```

And use it this way

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let Item of arrImages">
    <label>{{Item | extractnamefromfilepath}}</label>
    <img src="{{Item}}">
    <button (click)="ChangeImage(Item)">Change</button>
</ng-container>
```

In ChangeImage function, Item will now be the **Path** of the image, but you can extract the name from the path with a function similar to the pipe one.

---

**Second way - Class**

Make a class like

```
export class ImageHolder 
{
    imgPath: string;
    imgName: string;

    constructor(imgPath: string)
    {
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
        imgName = extractNameFromPath(imgPath);
    }

    extractNameFromPath(imgPath: string) : string
    {
        // Split full path into small chunks of path (img/image.png => ['img','image.png']
        var splittedPath = value.split('/');

        // Sub the 4 last char of the last splittedPath chunk ('image.png' => 'image')
        return splittedPath[splittedPath.length - 1]
              .substring(splittedPath[splittedPath.length - 1].length - 4);
    }
}
```

Then make your array like

```
arrImgs = [];
arrImgs.push(new ImageHolder('Front.png'), new ImageHolder('Back.png'), etc..);
```

And use it like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let Item of arrImages">
    <label>{{Item.imgName}}</label>
    <img src="{{Item.imgPath}}">
    <button (click)="ChangeImage(Item.)">Change</button>
</ng-container>
```

In ChangeImage function, item will now be an **ImageHolder object**.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. It does solve the problem and your answer still taught me a lot. But yurzui's answer is definitely the easiest solution. Thanks though!

Comment: Ahah no problem, glad you solved it :). And I actually learned somthing too